# Query Builder Class - CodeIgniter 4

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, where-clause

Please I need some help the Query Builder Class, this should be simple but I've been several days trying to solve it.

This is my Controller function, which receives data via POST from a IOT device:

```
public function gettopics(){

    $password = strip_tags($this->input->post('gdp'));

    if ($password == GET_DATA_PASSWORD){

           $device_sn = strip_tags($this->input->post('sn'));
           $result = $this->Getdata_model->gettopics($device_sn);
           **** echo "<br>#".ROOT_TOPIC."/".$result[0]['device_topic']."#".MQTT_USER."#".MQTT_PASSWORD."# ";
    }else{
           echo "access denied";
    }
}
```

And this is my model:

```
public function gettopics($device_sn){

    $this->db->SELECT('device_topic');
    $this->db->FROM('devices');
    $this->db->WHERE('device_sn',$device_sn);
    $result = $this->db->get()->result_array();
    return $result;
}
```

Everything works fine when the field 'device_sn' in WHERE clause is a numeric value (INT, BIGINT, etc) but I need this field to be a VARCHAR.

'device_sn' is the device serial number and it contains characters too.

I get this:

> `A PHP Error was encountered</h4><p>Severity: Notice</p><p>Message:  Undefined offset: 0</p><p>Filename: controllers/Getdata.php</p><p>Line Number: 27`

Line 27 in Getdata controller is the one marked with **** (echo). This is the same error I get when there is not device matching the serial number, but in this case in sure the serial number exists ... I only change the data type in 'device_sn' field from INT to varchar and quits working.

Comment: DId you check the database table? If so, what are the serial numbers in de device_sn column? And what is the format for this column?

Comment: There was some extra caracters on the query ... my code was adding "\n\r" to the select sentence. i already have fixed this issue. very Sorry to waste your time and thanks !!